# Oracle SQL formatting a query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Given the following tables:

PERSON:

```
PK  person_id             NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL 
    first_name            VARCHAR2(100) 
    preferred_first_name  VARCHAR2(100) 
    last_name             VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL 
    date_of_birth         DATE 
    hire_date             DATE 
    occupation            VARCHAR2(1)
```

ADDRESS:

```
PK  address_id            NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL 
FK  person_id             NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL 
    address_type          VARCHAR2(4)   NOT NULL 
    street_line_1         VARCHAR2(100) 
    city                  VARCHAR2(100) 
    state                 VARCHAR2(100) 
    zip_code              VARCHAR2(30)
```

I have to write a query to select data in the following format:

```
last_name | home_address                      |             billing_address
---------------
Smith     | 89 Lyon Circle, Clifton, VA 12345 | 25 Science Park, New Haven, CT 06511                       
Jones     | 212 Maple Ave, Manassas, VA 22033 | 275 Winchester Ave, New Haven, CT 06511
```

This is why I have so far but the error keeps saying I have 'invalid number of arguments'

```
SELECT
  last_name, 
  CASE WHEN address_type = 'Home' 
       THEN CONCAT(street_line_1, city, state, zip_code SEPARATOR ',') 
  END Home_address, 
  case when address.address_type = 'Bill' 
       THEN CONCAT(street_line_1, city, state, address.Zip_code SEPARATOR ',') 
  END Billing_address 
FROM person, address 
WHERE person_id= person_id 
GROUP BY address_type;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my query?

Comment: When you get an error, cut & paste the exact error message into your question, rather than paraphrasing. You might leave out an important detail.

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of the old syntax from the 1980s.

Comment: Just as a side observation, don't you think allocating 100 characters for STATE and 30 for ZIP_CODE is a bit excessive?  If this is the US (as your example suggests) you only need 2 characters for STATE and 10 for zip_code (and that only if using the full USPS zip+4).  True, they are varchar2, so will not take up that extra space on disk, but they WILL require the full potential size in memory, and that could potentially lead to 'out of memory' problems somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 2):

In order to concatenate more than two string, you would have to nest CONCAT calls, as seen [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm).

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(street_line_1, city), state), zip_code)
```

But that doesn't add the separator unfortunately. Try using the concat operator, ||.

```
street_line_1 || ',' || city || ',' || state || ',' || zip_code
```